# CKEditor5 styles dropdown

Tags: ckeditor5

Sorry if this has been addressed before.

CKEditor4 provided feature of Styles dropdown where we were able to add custom CSS classes. However, I do not see this feature in CKEditor5 version.

[Styles dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asHO7.png)

Could someone please guide on this if there is any other way to get the Styles dropdown with CKEditor5?

Answer (score 0):

A styles feature has been added, see their [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/style.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).